# How do I create JSON array in this specific structure

Tags: javascript, angular

This is the array format `[{"name":"Rose","number":"+919224512555"},{"name":"smith","number":"+91975555224"}]` I got from my angular form that having a dynamic table with columns name and number respectively.

I want to convert above mentioned array into the below mentioned format to store in database.

```
"name": [
            {
                "first_name": "Rose",
                "formatted_name": "Rose",
            },
            {
                "first_name": "smith",
                "formatted_name": "Smith",
            },
        ] ,          


"phones": [
            {
                "phone": "+919224512555",
                "type": "HOME"
            },
            {
                "phone": "+91975555224",
                "type": "HOME",
            }
        ],
```

I'm using angular for front-end development and laravel for back-end

Comment: You'll have to loop over the original array and process each entry one by one. Alternatively if you are a bit more advanced you could use a reducer.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe this would be better way of doing it

```
const data = [
  { name: "Rose", number: "+919224512555" },
  { name: "smith", number: "+91975555224" },
]

const mapped = {
    "name": data.map((item) => ({
        first_name: item.name,
        formatted_name: item.name, // do your own formatting here
    })),
    "phone": data.map((item) => ({
        phone: item.number,
        type: item.number, // do your own processing here
    }))
}

console.log(mapped)
```

hope it benefits you

Answer (score 0):

You could do with `Array#reducer`

```js
const arr = [{"name":"Rose","number":"+919224512555"},{"name":"smith","number":"+91975555224"}];

const res = arr.reduce((a,{name,number})=>{
       a.name = a.name||[];
       a.name.push({first_name:name,formatted_name:name});
       a.phones = a.phones||[];
       a.phones.push({phone:number,type:'HOME'});
       return a;
},{})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score -1):

The below code should do help you restructure your JSON object

```
const req_body = [
    { name:"Rose", number:"+919224512555" },
    { name:"smith", number:"+91975555224"}
]

const restrutured_body = { 
    name: [], 
    phone: [] 
};

req_body.forEach((item) => {
    restrutured_body.name.push({
        first_name: item.name,
        formatted_name: item.name
    });

    restrutured_body.phone.push({
        phone: item.number,
        type: 'HOME'
    });
});

console.log(restrutured_body);
```

Comment: example - https://repl.it/@iSanjayAchar/MajesticBetterApi#index.js